# How to refresh element in cakephp using jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

```
<div class="mytabelement">
     <?php     
        if($newstatus[0]['users']['status'] == 'complete'){
          echo $this -> Form -> postLink(__('update'), array(
    'controller'=>'orders','action' => 'user_satus','admin'=>false), array(
    'class' => 'uiBtn uiBtnBlue','id'=>'runloGc','title' => 'Run Logic'), 
    __('Are you sure you want update user?'));
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Above is my element data which come on everypage of my site, i just need to refresh this element every 2 minuts,  without refreshing the page..? is it possible please help..!!

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.post(url,data,function(data){
        $(".mytabelement").html(data);
    });
},2*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

here i am giving you just example.

you can change it in your way to using in response for `html` or `Json` as you want.

and i hope you will familiar with, ajax data type.

```
     <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    Notifications();  // this will call only one time thats first body load time 
                    setInterval("Notifications()", 2*60*1000);  // this will call each 5000ms
                    //60000
                });
                function Notifications(){
var url = "http://example.com/user/list"
                    //alert("Notify");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        success: function(data){
                            var test=eval(data);
                            $("#dii").empty();
                            for(i=0;i<test.length;i++){

                                $("#dii").append("<b>"+test[i]['name']+"</b>");
                                $("#dii").append(":");
                                $("#dii").append(test[i]['post']);
                                $("#dii").append("<br />");

                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            </script>
```

And also for your controller action set your logic and just output the data in you.

Please let me know if i can help you more

Comment: if i could help you, more pls let me know.